# pylint - String statement has no effect (pointless-string-statement) for Module doc string

Tags: python, pylint

Please advise how to fix the pylint complaining.

pylint complains `String statement has no effect (pointless-string-statement)` for the doc string at the top of the module file.

```
"""Utilities for the online realtime model serving.
Consider the latency of the serving response
"""
```

If removed it, then complain `1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-module-docstring)`.

## Environment

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.9

$ pylint --version
pylint 2.14.4
astroid 2.11.6
Python 3.7.9 (v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 15 2020, 01:31:08) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]

$ pip install pylint --upgrade
No update occurs
```

Comment: That sounds like you had more than one string at the top of the file - only the first one counts as a docstring.

Comment: I think Jason is right but to be sure can you show everything in your file until the first import and the actual line and column of the pointless-string-statement message ?

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem, when the docstring was below the imports. When I put it above the imports, below the license header, `pylint` was happy.

Where is it in your file?